# Mulesoft: taking more than 3 min to generate txt file

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

We are reading a txt file which is size of less than 100 KB and generating output txt file using below transformation logic. To generate output txt file in production, it is taking **more than 3 minutes** . Is there anyway to reduce processing time.

- Mule Runtime: 4.2.1

```
import * from dw::core::Strings
//output application/csv
output application/flatfile schemaPath = "output-fixed-witdh.ffd" , segmentIdent = "output-fixed-witdh"
---

payload map {
    FirstName_Out: $.ParticipantFirstName,
    LastName_Out: $.ParticipantLastName,
    IssueDate_Out: ($.ReimbursementDate splitBy ("/") map (if(sizeOf($)==1) "0" ++ $ else $) joinBy "/")  as Date {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"} as String {format: "MMddyy"},
    Amount_Out: ($.Amount as Number*100) as String {format: "0000000000"},
    CheckType_Out: $.Method,
    CheckNumber_Out: $.PaymentNumber
}
```

Below is the schema used:

```
form: FIXEDWIDTH
id: 'output-fixed-witdh'
name: 'output-fixed-witdh'
values: 
- { name: 'FirstName_Out', usage: M, type: String, length: 20 }
- { name: 'LastName_Out', usage: M, type: String, length: 20 }
- { name: 'IssueDate_Out', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
- { name: 'Amount_Out', usage: M, type: String, length: 10 }
- { name: 'CheckType_Out', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
- { name: 'CheckNumber_Out', usage: M, type: String, length: 8 }
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, can you add a fragment of the input? Is it a flat file also? Do you have an ffd schema for it?

Comment: I agree with @JorgeGarcia. There is too little context to understand the problem. Also, are you sure the time is spent in this transformation?

Comment: added fragment details in the question it self. Please check it.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the time is consumed in this specific transformation? How many records does the file contain?

Comment: only one file size of 7KB and having 70 rows and 13 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is Windows issue. Try it on Linux. We have app which does work on Windows for 6 hours and 10 minutes on Linux. Give it a try.

Comment: our prod servers are running on Windows, no way to try.